# Get header (code) from EXE

Tags: exe, reverse-engineering

i have this "updater/launcher" program for updating our (game) client,

however the source code is lost, ive asked the creator of the program and his HDD crashed so the only way to re-write the program is to get the "header" from the exe
i have no idea what it looks like or know the programming language

INFO:
Its a updater / launcher to update our client, it downloads ".div"  files and adds them to a "data.pak" (1 big file with files are folders inside)

Is it possible to reverse engineer this file to get the source / header from the code?

Here is the files that i have: https://www.firedrive.com/file/D0BFD7800336C6A4

if you need more info, just ask, ill try to post

Comment: What do you mean by _"header"_? The PE format (which is what Windows executables use) contains headers, but they very rarely have any code in them. Are you talking about C/C++ header files? If so, that's an entirely different concept. What you'll find in the `.text` section of the executable is machine code, which you can disassemble into assembly language code.

Comment: The code to add the DIV files to the data.pak, they said its header code, but iam not sure of it